# how to solve Uncaught (in promise) error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting this error in inspect->console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7W63.png)

this is my code, getting error in line - ProductHelper.create(data)

```
      if (this.props.data !== undefined) {
            data.product_id = this.props.data.product_id;
            data.is_active = is_active;
            ProductHelper.update(data, this.props.data.product_id)
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.code == 200) {
                        alert("Product successfully updated!");
                        this.props.getProducts();
                        this.props.setVisibility(false);
                    } else {
                        throw "Incorrect seller id";
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    throw err;
                });
        } else {
            ProductHelper.create(data)
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.code == 200) {
                        alert("Product successfully created!");
                        this.props.getProducts();
                        this.props.setVisibility(false);
                    } else if (data.code == 401) {
                        alert("Your product limit has exceeded!");
                    } else {
                        throw "error";
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    throw err;
                });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert("Error creating. Try Again Later!");
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

what should i do?

Comment: Please post some code so we can understand what is happening.

Comment: can you please share the controller?

Comment: @EduardHasanaj is this code enough or shall i post the whole code. i dono where the error is.so i don't post the code

Comment: @Keerthika You are throwing an error inside catch. You should not throw error there if the outer function is not enclosed in a try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I think the promise is failing and not able to find an error block. You will have to add a catch statement with the promise.

```
promise
.then((res) => {})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```